# Convert unicode character to base character

Tags: python

I have an array of bytes.. `b'containing a b\xd1\x96cycle'`

I am trying to convert this string into it's ascii equivalent: `containing a bicycle`

How can I achieve this?

Note that this is just one example, there are other examples such as:

`containing a \xd1\x95eaplane` -> `containing a seaplane`

`containing an \xd0\xb0irplane` -> `containing an airplane`

I do not want to do static replacements via a dictionary lookup.

Is there a way to do this on the fly?

I've tried this but it removes the character completely:

`question.encode('ascii', 'ignore')` -> `bcontaining a bcycle'`

Note that I am trying to find the ACTUAL character, not the "lookalike" characters that are being represented in unicode.

Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear, the "actual letter" in `\xd1\x95eaplane` is the cyrillic character "dze" (\u0455). What you are after is to convert this to its ascii look-alike, `s` (\u0074, which is just one byte in utf-8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be going in the wrong direction.  If you have bytes and you want a string, that's a ***decode*** operation, not an ***encode***.  This works just fine and I think gives you what you want:

```
print(b'containing a b\xd1\x96cycle'.decode("utf-8"))
```

Result:

```
containing a bіcycle
```

And just to be clear, when you say:

> I have a string that looks like this b'containing a b\xd1\x96cycle'

you don't actually have a string, you have a ***bytes*** object...an array of bytes.

UPDATE: I never like to leave a question half answered, even if it involves something a bit different than what was asked for....

Unicode has no notion of a mapping down to ASCII characters...of turning Unicode "look-alikes" into their ASCII equivalents.  There are, however, packages that attempt to do this.  They must, however, be doing some kind of out-of-band mapping under the hood.  One such package is [Unidecode](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/).  Here's what it looks like to use that package to come up with what I believe is what you wanted:

```
import unidecode
unicodeBytes = b'containing a b\xd1\x96cycle'
unicodeStr = unicodeBytes.decode("utf-8")
mappedUnicodeStr = unidecode.unidecode(unicodeStr)
asciiBytes = mappedUnicodeStr.encode("ascii")
print(asciiBytes)
```

Result:

```
b'containing a bicycle'
```

The characters of the resulting bytes object are all plain ASCII.  Do check out the documentation for the [unidecode](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/) package, and note the caveats it discusses.

Comment: Updated my question. I want to find the actual base character, rather than the "lookalike" character as mentioned in another answer

Comment: You say you don't want to do a dictionary lookup to come up with the ASCII equivalent of a specific Unicode character.  I believe that a dictionary lookup is the only way to do this.  There is no notion in Unicode of one character being a "look-alike" to another.  So any such conversion that you could do would by definition involve additional information...a mapping...between Unicode and ASCII.

Comment: @Sam - Think I have you covered with the update to my answer.  I think this is the best you'll ever be able to do.  Hopefully it's just what you're looking for.

Comment: This worked perfectly for my use case. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at byte representations of strings containing ascii look-alikes encoded in UTF-8. E.g., `\xd1\x96` is `\u0455`, "Cyrillic small letter dze". To view it, *decode* the string specifying the "utf-8" encoding. (Optional if this is your system default.)

```
>>> original = b"\xd1\x95eaplane"
>>> nice = original.decode("utf-8")
>>> print(nice)
ѕeaplane
```

Note that this looks like an *s*, but **it is not an *s***.

Comment: I updated my question. How can I get the actual letter?

Answer (score -1):

In python, strings are internally represented as unicode, from which the strings can be *encoded* into the desired encoding (in this case *ascii*).

[https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#:~:text=Python's%20string%20type%20uses%20the,all%20these%20different%20possible%20characters](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#:%7E:text=Python%27s%20string%20type%20uses%20the,all%20these%20different%20possible%20characters).

> Python’s string type uses the Unicode Standard for representing characters, which lets Python programs work with all these different possible characters.

```
unicode_representation = b'containing a b\xd1\x96cycle'.decode("utf8")
ascii_encoded = unicode_representation.encode("ascii", "ignore")
```

However, as mentioned, in this case "i" will be removed from "bicycle" in the output, as it can no be encoded as ascii.

You can see that the characters are different unicode codepoints by calling `ord()` on the character.

```
s = b'containing a b\xd1\x96cycle'
u = s.decode("utf8")
for c in u:
    print(c, ord(c))
```

Will give you:

```
c 99
o 111
n 110
t 116
a 97
i 105
n 110
i 105
n 110
g 103
  32
a 97
  32
b 98
і 1110
c 99
y 121
c 99
l 108
e 101
```

As you can see `105` != `1110`, where `105` can be encoded as ascii, and `1110` can not, even though visually they look the same.

If you want to get the closest ascii representation to the unicode you will need a mapping defined somewhere to perform the conversion.

Something like this:

```
similar_ascii = {
    1110: "i",
}
def convert_to_ascii_codepoints(s):
    result = []
    for c in s:
        converted_char = similar_ascii.get(ord(c), None)
        if converted_char:
            c = converted_char
        result.append(c)
    return "".join(result)

s = b'containing a b\xd1\x96cycle'
u = s.decode("utf8")
result = convert_to_ascii_codepoints(u)
result.encode("ascii")
```

It looks like this package may have the necessary mappings and conversion functions defined for you.

https://github.com/ajanin/uni2ascii

** Untested **

```
from uni2ascii import uni2ascii

s = b'containing a b\xd1\x96cycle'
ascii_string = uni2ascii(s)
```

Comment: This code will fail.  The original bytes array encodes a string that can't be represented by ***ascii***.  Your second line of code will therefore throw an exception.

Comment: Yes, with "ignore", it will not be output.